# logcat error in my barcode reader app

Tags: android

I have this error in my logcat . How can I solve this? My app is a barcode reader.
When I run my app it crashes every time.

```
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.BarcodeScanningApp.BarcodeScanningAppActivity$1.onClick(BarcodeScanningAppActivity.java:31)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-14 10:53:40.994: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my manifest is:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name=".BarcodeScanningAppActivity" >
<intent-filter >
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".inputdat" />
<activity android:name=".start" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: code??......................

Comment: code for the activity?

Comment: what is line 31 of your BarcodeScanningAppActivity? You need to provide the code to get any solutions

Answer (score 0):

First of All you need to Declare activity source code 
but by my experience
When you call onActivityForResult you pass the button id so 
first check you pass exact name for barcode button as it declare in XML File and as it declare in your class
Second Check perform action method to handle result for barcode

For sure your exception happen when the barcode scan and try to handle result

These Permission Required to be declared in manifest

```
<!-- required for bar code scanner -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Remember CaptureActivity declare in Manifest